# Can I access my VMware workstation intranet VMs through a public IP address

Tags: windows, nat, vmware-workstation, dnat

I have a Windows Server with a public IP address (`102.1.1.1`) and I've installed VMware workstation on it, creating several VMs on it.

The VMs use intranet IP addresses, such as `10.0.0.1`, `10.0.0.2`.

I have a question, whether exists a network technology that can map the public IP address and port to the intranet IP address and port?

I mean:

When being in the public network access the `102.1.1.1:1001` and translate to `10.0.0.1: 80`, and access the `102.1.1.1:1002` and translate to `10.0.0.2:80`?

I've got some NAT/NAP knowledge, but I am not sure it can achieve my requirement. Who can give me any advice?

Comment: NAT is exactly what you are looking for. Especially the port mapping feature.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is destination NAT or port forwarding. Thing is that you'd have to use a firewall to do the translation. Almost any software firewall can do the job. Even you don't explicitly say it I assume you have a router so you can connect your server to the  internet with the public IP address so log in that router and look for a section related to port mapping or destination NAT, from there you can just do what you posted: any traffic incoming to the public IP address with a specific port/service translate it to the intranet VM in a different port. Hope that helps!